# How to know if a text is too long for a textblock?

Tags: xaml

I have two textblocks. I want to set a custom text to the first one and if it's too long to be displayed entirely, I want to continue it to the second text box and a third one if necessary.

How can I do that ? Is there a way to know if a text will be truncated or wrap in a textblock ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Just use TextWrapping="Wrap"

Comment: Thanks @dellywheel but that's not what I want to do ;) I want my text displayed on different location not just from top to bottom. For example, the first part on the upper left corner and the remaining part on the middle of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no out of the box solution for this. what you could try is reading the length of the textbox (ActualWidth property) and see if this is longer then the container it's in.

Checking the length of the string is not a valid option for most fonts since W takes up more space than an I in most fonts.

```
        if (TextBlock1.ActualWidth > 100)
        {
            TextBlock2.text = yourtext;
        }
```

make sure text wrapping is set to false.

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but if `RichTextBlock` is available then this is incorrect, see [RichTextBlock.OverflowContentTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227594)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it)
You can just set TextWrapping attribute of the first TextBlock to "Wrap" and it'll work fine!

```
<TextBlock Text="Long text here" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

**EDIT**

Put whole text to TextBlock1. TextBlock limit HERE is 50, you can set it as much as u want.

```
string some = TextBlock1.Text;
if (some.Length > 50)
{
   TextBlock2.Text = some.Substring(50, some.Lenght - 50);
   some = some.Remove(51, some.Lenght - 50);
   TextBlock1.Text = some;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want to do ;) I want my text displayed on different location not just from top to bottom. For example, the first part on the upper left corner and the remaining part on the middle of the page.

Comment: @SeyoS
Check the EDIT. I found the solution.

Comment: That's exactly what I did while waiting for a better solution. It's not perfect as the display length of a textblock depend on the chosen font.

Comment: @SeyoS
So i dont have any other solutions(